# PhpStorm - Index file doesn't exist error

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I am trying to familiarize myself with PHP and PhpStorm. When I try to run any PHP file it gives me following error:

> 404 Not Found: Index file doesn't exist.

And when I try to execute my PHP code via small HTML code then it doesn't stop at breakpoint.

Is there a config which I am missing?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<h1>message</h1>

<form action="http://pushchat.local:44447/api.php" method="post">

user_id: <input type="text" name="user_id" value="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"/><br/>
text: <textarea name="text">Hello, world!</textarea><br/>
<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="message"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

// This is the server API for the PushChat iPhone app. To use the API, the app
// sends an HTTP POST request to our URL. The POST data contains a field "cmd"
// that indicates what API command should be executed.

try
{
    // Are we running in development or production mode? You can easily switch
    // between these two in the Apache VirtualHost configuration.
    if (!defined('APPLICATION_ENV'))
        define('APPLICATION_ENV', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production');

    // In development mode, we show all errors because we obviously want to 
    // know about them. We don't do this in production mode because that might
    // expose critical details of our app or our database. Critical PHP errors
    // will still be logged in the PHP and Apache error logs, so it's always
    // a good idea to keep an eye on them.
    if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
        ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    }
    else
    {
        error_reporting(0);
        ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
    }

    // Load the config file. I prefer to keep all configuration settings in a
    // separate file so you don't have to mess around in the main code if you
    // just want to change some settings.
    require_once 'api_config.php';
    $config = $config[APPLICATION_ENV];

    // In development mode, we fake a delay that makes testing more realistic.
    // You're probably running this on a fast local server but in production
    // mode people will be using it on a mobile device over a slow connection.
    if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
        sleep(2);

    // To keep the code clean, I put the API into its own class. Create an
    // instance of that class and let it handle the request.
    $api = new API($config);
    $api->handleCommand();

    echo "OK" . PHP_EOL;
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // The code throws an exception when something goes horribly wrong; e.g.
    // no connection to the database could be made. In development mode, we
    // show these exception messages. In production mode, we simply return a
    // "500 Server Error" message.

    if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
        var_dump($e);
    else
        exitWithHttpError(500);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function exitWithHttpError($error_code, $message = '')
{
    switch ($error_code)
    {
        case 400: header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"); break;
        case 403: header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"); break;
        case 404: header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); break;
        case 500: header("HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error"); break;
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    if ($message != '')
        header('X-Error-Description: ' . $message);

    exit;
}

function isValidUtf8String($string, $maxLength, $allowNewlines = false)
{
    if (empty($string) || strlen($string) > $maxLength)
        return false;

    if (mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8') === false)
        return false;

    // Don't allow control characters, except possibly newlines 
    for ($t = 0; $t < strlen($string); $t++)
    {
        $ord = ord($string{$t});

        if ($allowNewlines && ($ord == 10 || $ord == 13))
            continue;

        if ($ord < 32)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function truncateUtf8($string, $maxLength)
{
    $origString = $string;
    $origLength = $maxLength;

    while (strlen($string) > $origLength)
    {
        $string = mb_substr($origString, 0, $maxLength, 'utf-8');
        $maxLength--;
    }

    return $string;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class API
{
    // Because the payload only allows for 256 bytes and there is some overhead
    // we limit the message text to 190 characters.
    const MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 190;

    private $pdo;

    function __construct($config)
    {
        // Create a connection to the database.
        $this->pdo = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], 
            $config['db']['username'], 
            $config['db']['password'],
            array());

        // If there is an error executing database queries, we want PDO to
        // throw an exception. Our exception handler will then exit the script
        // with a "500 Server Error" message.
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        // We want the database to handle all strings as UTF-8.
        $this->pdo->query('SET NAMES utf8');
    }

    function handleCommand()
    {
        // Figure out which command the client sent and let the corresponding
        // method handle it. If the command is unknown, then exit with an error
        // message.
        if (isset($_POST['cmd']))
        {
            switch (trim($_POST['cmd']))
            {
                case 'join': $this->handleJoin(); return;
                case 'leave': $this->handleLeave(); return;
                case 'update': $this->handleUpdate(); return;
                case 'message': $this->handleMessage(); return;
            }
        }

        exitWithHttpError(400, 'Unknown command');
    }

    // The "join" API command registers a user to receive notifications that
    // are sent in a specific "chat room". Each chat room is identified by a
    // secret code. All the users who register with the same secret code can
    // see each other's messages.
    //
    // This command takes the following POST parameters:
    //
    // - user_Id:  A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
    // - token: The device's device token. Must be a string of 64 hexadecimal
    //          characters, or "0" if no token is available yet.
    // - name:  The nickname of the user. Must be a UTF-8 string of maximum 255
    //          bytes. Only the first 20 bytes are actually shown in the push 
    //          notifications.
    // - code:  The secret code that identifies the chat room. Must be a UTF-8
    //          string of maximum 255 bytes.
    //
    function handleJoin()
    {
        $userId = $this->getUserId();
        $token = $this->getDeviceToken(true);
        $name = $this->getString('name', 255);
        $code = $this->getString('code', 255);

        // When the client sends a "join" command, we add a new record to the
        // active_users table. We identify the client by the user_id that it
        // provides. When the client sends a "leave" command, we delete its
        // record from the active_users table.

        // It is theoretically possible that a client sends a "join" command
        // while its user_id is still present in active_users (because it did not
        // send a "leave" command). In that case, we simply remove the old
        // record first and then insert the new one.

        $this->pdo->beginTransaction();

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM active_users WHERE user_Id = ?');
        $stmt->execute(array($userId));

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO active_users (user_Id, device_token, nickname, secret_code, ip_address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $stmt->execute(array($userId, $token, $name, $code, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

        $this->pdo->commit();
    }

    // The "leave" API command removes a user from a chat room. That user will
    // no longer receive push notifications for messages sent to that room.
    //
    // This command takes the following POST parameters:
    //
    // - user_id: A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
    //
    function handleLeave()
    {
        $userId = $this->getUserId();
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM active_users WHERE user_Id = ?');
        $stmt->execute(array($userId));
    }

    // The "update" API command gives a user a new device token.
    //
    // This command takes the following POST parameters:
    //
    // - user_id:  A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
    // - token: The device's device token. Must be a string of 64 hexadecimal
    //          characters.
    //
    function handleUpdate()
    {
        $userId = $this->getUserId();
        $token = $this->getDeviceToken(false);
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('UPDATE active_users SET device_token = ? WHERE user_Id = ?');
        $stmt->execute(array($token, $userId));
    }

    // The "message" API command sends a message to all users who are registered
    // with the same secret code as the sender of the message.
    //
    // This command takes the following POST parameters:
    //
    // - user_id: A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
    // - text: The message text. Must be a UTF-8 string of maximum 190 bytes.
    //
    function handleMessage()
    {
        $userId = $this->getUserId();
        $text = $this->getString('text', self::MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, true);

        // First, we get the record for the sender of the message from the
        // active_users table. That gives us the nickname, device token, and
        // secret code for that user.

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM active_users WHERE user_Id = ? LIMIT 1');
        $stmt->execute(array($userId));
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        if ($user !== false)
        {
            // Put the sender's name and the message text into the JSON payload
            // for the push notification.
            $payload = $this->makePayload($user->nickname, $text);

            // Find the device tokens for all other users who are registered
            // for this secret code. We exclude the device token of the sender
            // of the message, so he will not get a push notification. We also
            // exclude users who have not submitted a valid device token yet.
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT device_token FROM active_users WHERE secret_code = ? AND device_token <> ? AND device_token <> '0'");
            $stmt->execute(array($user->secret_code, $user->device_token));
            $tokens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

            // Send out a push notification to each of these devices.
            foreach ($tokens as $token)
            {
                $this->addPushNotification($token, $payload);
            }
        }
    }

    // Retrieves the user identifier from the POST data. If the user_id does not
    // appear to be valid, the script exits with an error message.
    function getUserId()
    {
        if (!isset($_POST['user_id']))
            exitWithHttpError(400, 'Missing user_id');

        $userId = trim(urldecode($_POST['user_id']));
        if (!$this->isValidUserId($userId))
            exitWithHttpError(400, 'Invalid user_id');

        return $userId;
    }

    // Checks whether the format of the user identifier is correct (40 hex
    // characters or 32 for the simulator).
    function isValidUserId($userId)
    {
        if (strlen($userId) != 40 && strlen($userId) != 32)  // 32 for simulator
            return false;

        if (preg_match("/^[0-9a-fA-F]+$/", $userId) == 0)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    // Retrieves the device token from the POST data. If the token does not
    // appear to be valid, the script exits with an error message.
    function getDeviceToken($mayBeEmpty = false)
    {
        if (!isset($_POST['token']))
            exitWithHttpError(400, 'Missing device token');

        $token = trim($_POST['token']);

        // The "join" command allows a token value of "0" to be specified,
        // which is necessary in case the client did not yet obtain a device
        // token at that point. We allow such clients to join, but they will
        // not receive any notifications until they provide a valid token
        // using the "update" command.
        if ($mayBeEmpty && $token == "0")
            return $token;

        if (!$this->isValidDeviceToken($token))
            exitWithHttpError(400, 'Invalid device token');

        return $token;  
    }

    // Checks whether the format of the device token is correct (64 hexadecimal
    // characters). Note: we have no means to verify whether the device token
    // was really issued by APNS and corresponds to an actual device.
    function isValidDeviceToken($deviceToken)
    {
        if (strlen($deviceToken) != 64)
            return false;

        if (preg_match("/^[0-9a-fA-F]{64}$/", $deviceToken) == 0)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    // Looks in the POST data for a field with the given name. If the field
    // is not a valid UTF-8 string, or it is too long, the script exits with
    // an error message.
    function getString($name, $maxLength, $allowNewlines = false)
    {
        if (!isset($_POST[$name]))
            exitWithHttpError(400, "Missing $name");

        $string = trim($_POST[$name]);
        if (!isValidUtf8String($string, $maxLength, $allowNewlines))
            exitWithHttpError(400, "Invalid $name");

        return $string;
    }

    // Creates the JSON payload for the push notification message. The "alert"
    // text has the following format: "sender_name: message_text". Recipients
    // can obtain the name of the sender by parsing the alert text up to the
    // first colon followed by a space.
    function makePayload($senderName, $text)
    {
        // Convert the nickname of the sender to JSON and truncate to a maximum
        // length of 20 bytes (which may be less than 20 characters).
        $nameJson = $this->jsonEncode($senderName);
        $nameJson = truncateUtf8($nameJson, 20);

        // Convert and truncate the message text
        $textJson = $this->jsonEncode($text);
        $textJson = truncateUtf8($textJson, self::MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH);

        // Combine everything into a JSON string
        $payload = '{"aps":{"alert":"' . $nameJson . ': ' . $textJson . '","sound":"default"}}';
        return $payload;
    }

    // We don't use PHP's built-in json_encode() function because it converts
    // UTF-8 characters to \uxxxx. That eats up 6 characters in the payload for
    // no good reason, as JSON already supports UTF-8 just fine.
    function jsonEncode($text)
    {
        static $from = array("\\", "/", "\n", "\t", "\r", "\b", "\f", '"');
        static $to = array('\\\\', '\\/', '\\n', '\\t', '\\r', '\\b', '\\f', '\"');
        return str_replace($from, $to, $text);
    }

    // Adds a push notification to the push queue. The notification will not
    // be sent immediately. The server runs a separate script, push.php, which 
    // periodically checks for new entries in this database table and sends
    // them to the APNS servers.
    function addPushNotification($deviceToken, $payload)
    {
        // Payloads have a maximum size of 256 bytes. If the payload is too
        // large (which shouldn't happen), we won't send this notification.
        if (strlen($payload) <= 256)
        {
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO push_queue (device_token, payload, time_queued) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())');
            $stmt->execute(array($deviceToken, $payload));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We won't be able to help you without an ability to reproduce the error.

Comment: Did you call your index file `index.php`?  Are you certain your webserver is configured to support PHP?  You should probably provide some more detail in your question.

Comment: I am using MAMP for PHP and MySQL. It runs fine. When I run the HTML code it creates records in database via api.php. In my API folder I have 3 files 1>index.php 2> api.php 3> api_config.php. I am trying to debug so that it helps me learn better.

Comment: Is it really Index.php, not index.php?  I don't know that the webserver will find it by default if that is the case and certainly you will get 404 if you try to navigate to index.php.

Comment: So you are certain your webserver supports PHP but you can't get any to run?  And when you put `index.php` in your public root and you navigate to it, you get a 404, but you won't show us the file contents?  I dunno I guess I give up.

Comment: Please dont give up:) as I am new to this and I am def making basic mistake. I have attached my code if that helps.You can get the whole code from [link] (http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2) and search for 'download the PushChatServer code'. This download all the api and test html file which I am refering. I want to bring to your notice that I am able to run successfully via HTML test and create databut it is just that it doesn't stop at breakpoint in phpstorm. Also, please note that it is more important for me to make my debugger work.

Comment: I was able to resolve 404 Not Found: Index file doesn't exist.I had to correct the port number for api.php phpstorm configuration. I am still unable to resolve not stopping at breakpoint issue.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i faced the similar problem.
In fact phpstorm is able to open files by two ways:

1. First create/open project and then open files within the project
   (this is the prefered way)
2. Opening external files

> To open an external file do one of the following:
>
> > Choose File | Open on the main menu and select the desired file in the dialog box that opens. Drag the required file from the Explorer
> >     (Windows), File Browser (Linux), or Finder (OS) and drop it to the
> >     editor. The file will open for editing in a new tab.

So if you open your files using the first way (through project) you shouldn't face the "404 Not Found: Index file doesn't exist." problem.

But when i use the second one (Opening external files) i see the same problem.